# Duplicate column in source excel file - Azure data factory copy activity

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I have duplicate column names in my source excel file(eg: 'P','P'). But both columns have different data. I am using copy activity of ADF to load excel data in my adls to sql server. How can I handle the situation of duplicate scenario. If I have two columns in sql server as
first 'P' mapped to 'A' and second column 'P' to be mapped to 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

My excel config:
[image]

The excel file has duplicate columns because of which job is failing :
[image]

Solution:
uncheck the header in excel source :
[image]

Import schema:

[image]
The column mapping would be sequential number order

Output:
[image]

Note: you see the actual header values added as row in system.

So in excel data source, use sheet range value and start from A2 to avoid the actual header